# Form Validation - Text being sent as 'Undefined' to API

Tags: html, forms, angular, validation

I'm trying to send a textfield user input to a web api to validate it, however it's being sent as 'undefined' to my server

here is my code

form.component.html

```
 <div class="form-group">
      <label>Username</label>
      <!-- Rather than set an ngModel, we use the formControl directive to sync our input to the complexForm object. Notice that we are also setting the attribute we wish the corresponding input to sync with. We no longer need the name attribute, but can optionally add it. -->
      <input class="form-control" type="text" [validator]="complexForm.controls['username']" [formControl]="complexForm.controls['username']" >
    </div>
```

validator directive

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, Response, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';


import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Directive({
  selector: '[validator]'
})
export class ValidationDirective {
  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private http: Http) { }

  @Input('myUsername') username: string;

  @HostListener('focusout') onFocusOut() {
    this.isAvailable(this.username);
  }

  private isAvailable(username: string) {
    let url = 'myURL' + username;
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('user', sessionStorage.getItem('username'));
    headers.append('token', sessionStorage.getItem('token'));
    headers.append('accesstime', sessionStorage.getItem('AccessTime'));

    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

     this.http.get(url, options)
      .subscribe((res: Response) => console.log(res.json()));
  };

}
```

Why is the directive failing to take the input? and if it did, its sending the text input as 'undefined'. My aim is to send the username textfield when I focus out of the textfield to check if the username is taken. my Web API returns 'Y' or 'N' depending if the username is taken.

I'm very new to this, so I bet there would be some obvious mistakes.

thank you!

Comment: It should be `@Input() username: string;` instead of `@Input('myUsername') username: string;` . Tell me if it works

Comment: @RahulSingh Can't bind to 'myUsername' since it isn't a known property of 'input'

Comment: i have updated the comment check  that it was typo previously

Comment: how should the html look like? @RahulSingh

I'm not able to bind it to the username field

Comment: it should remain the same just change the ts file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `validator` both as **directive name** and **input**, then you should change your `@Input` part to

```
@Input('validator')
username: string;
```

Also, you are setting `FormControl` to directive `validator`'s input(username), so use `this.username.value` to retrieve its value.

```
@HostListener('focusout') onFocusOut() {
  this.isAvailable(this.username.value);
}
```

Sample **[plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/QQlFcjjQGOt4vCBeHgTd?p=preview)**.

Comment: Thank you! the Input decorator needed adjustments and it was being sent as undefined because of the FormControl class